# Trying to send byte[] via socket-io

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte, netty

I'm trying to send a byte array (from android client) to a websocket server made in Java (using netty socket-io)

So,

My client is this

```
public void sendImage(byte[] img) {
    Packet<byte[]> packet = new Packet<>(Parser.BINARY_EVENT);
    packet.data = img;
    socket.emit("new_image", packet);
}
```

And then my server is this:

```
server.addEventListener("new_image", byte[].class, new DataListener<byte[]>() {
        public void onData(SocketIOClient socketIOClient, byte[] data, AckRequest ackRequest) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Data Image Received");
        }
    });
```

But the server throws exception when a byte array is received

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '.' (code 0x2e) in base64 content

What is the problem?
I can't figure it out